# Accessing private class variable

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, properties, scope

While learning Python, I came accross this strange behavior :

Consider this simple class :

```
class Human(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.__name = name

  def description(self):
    print("Hello, my name is %s" % self.__name)
```

I want to avoid being able to alter the name after the object has been created.

If I use this :

```
MyHuman = Human("Andy")
MyHuman.__name = "Arthur"
MyHuman.age = 23

MyHuman.description()
print MyHuman.age
```

It doesn't change the name after the object instanciation, which is good because I want the instance variable to be private. On the other hand, I thought it would complain about accessing this variable. It doesn't even complain about accessing a mysterious "age" variable and prints it properly later.

I come from C# and it seems odd to me. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Your mistake was in believing that there are private variables in Python. The closest emulation of privacy is "pay no attention to that variable behind the curtain." If someone really wants to look behind the curtain, that's up to them. The official phrase is "consenting adults."

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) about Python objects and scopes.

Comment: Alrighty, but what about the "age" variable ? It's a bit confusing that you can create a variable on the fly (for example if I would simply make a typo), isn't it ?

Comment: How is it confusing that a typo can result in unexpected behavior in a computer program?

Comment: Can't you create variables on the fly in C#/Java/etc. with `int age = 23;`? Python lets you put these variables into the namespace of any object, because it's very convenient.

Comment: What I mean about confusing is that, instead of complaining about accessing a variable that doesn't exist in the class, it creates it... If you make a typo, you wouldn't notice you made this mistake... Do you understand ?

Comment: int age = 23 is not a class member. You're creating on purpose a new local variable. That makes a difference to me...

Comment: You used the proper syntax to assign the literal value `23` to a reference in the object. Python doesn't care whether you assign a reference to the `global` namespace, the `local` namespace, or some other object's namespace. There's nothing for it to complain about. I recommend reading some more of the documentation I linked above.

Comment: Yep, will do. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should know the following:

1. When you write to an attribute of an object, that does not exist, the python system will normally not complain, but just create a new attribute.
2. Private attributes are not protected by the Python system. That is by design decision.
3. Private attributes will be masked. The reason is, that there should be no clashes in the inheritance chain. The masking is done by some implicit renaming. Private attributes will have the *real* name

> ```
>   "_<className>__<attributeName>"
> ```

With that name, it can be accessed from outside. When accessed from inside the class, the name will be automatically changed correctly.

Comment: Coming from C#, the autocreation of class members is a bit disturbing for me. I'll get used to it :) Thank you for this explanation and your time.

Comment: @AndyM: You are welcome. Yes, Python indeed has some oddities and private members are one of them. You can count it to the fact, that Python is a scripting language and also proud of it ;) The designers wanted to have things explicit and don't wanted to have a type safe system as in other languages -- it just relies much more on openness and clarity. It enforces less, but relies on "good behavior" of the users.

Answer (score 2):

To <s>use</s> emulate readonly/private variables in Python, use `property` syntax. (Comments/other answers point out the variable can still be accessed if you know how--thanks for the heads up). Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> class Test:
        def __init__(self):
            self.__a = 1

        @property
        def a(self):
            return self.__a

>>> t = Test()
>>> t.a
1
>>> t.a = 2
AttributeError: cannot set attribute
>>> t.__a
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '__a'
```

Comment: `>>> t._Test__a`, `1`.

Comment: Is it possible that this example behaves differently on python 2.7 and 3.0 ? Is my IDE, using python 2.7, I get no error message and t.a = 2 is allowed. Testing it on an online 3.0 interpreter, I get the same error as you...

Comment: @AndyM yeah, that seems very possible. Have you tried defining your Python 2 class as a new-style class, `class Classname(object)`? That might make a difference. I don't know.

Comment: @Sam absolutely correct. Adding the (object) in my class declaration gives me the proper behavior. Very interesting ! Thanks for the precision!

Comment: @AndyM: I guess, that is the problem. Python 2 still supports "old style classes" -- and those have a total different behavior in some areas of attributes. The difference is that old style classes are started as Sam did. Python 3 only supports new style classes, as much I know, so it just ignores the syntax difference, I guess.